# How do i add bootsrap-rating to a number coming from an public API?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the bootstrap documentation that it only supports inputs, but can i append it to an object attribute through JQuery Ajax?

UPDATE:

tried this, but to no avail, tried parsing it as a number, it works in the html when i give the value a number

```
$('#albumsDisplay').append('<input id="input-6c" class="rating" data-min="0" data-max="1" data-step="0.1" value="' +JSON.parse( element.popularity) + '" data-size="xs">');

<input id="input-6c" class="rating" data-min="0" data-max="1" data-step="0.1" value=".56" data-size="xs">
```

Answer (score 0):

ah it seems i had to initialise the $('.rating').rating(); outside the success of the Ajax method....